# ELK to monitor Kubernetes

Tags: performance, azure, docker, kubernetes, elastic-stack

I have Kubernetes cluster runnning and created the ELK stack on different machine. 
Now I want to ship the logs from Kubernetes cluster to ELK how can I achieve it? 
The  ELK stack is outside the  cluster.

Comment: You can copy the logs from your containers, and then copy to your VM. It's easy but complicated. I suggest you can use an Azure File Share, persist volume with it to your containers and then mount it to your VM. So you can see the files in your VM and do not need to copy.

Comment: i cannot use any kind of metric beat configuration ? please correct me If I'm new to logging.

Comment: If you mean the Monitor to your container? If so, you can take a look at [Azure Monitor for containers overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/container-insights-overview?toc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Faks%2FTOC.json&bc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json).

Comment: we already have the log analytics and grafana dashboard but the logs are generated at a high rate and we intend to simplify this process.

Comment: So you can just improve the monitor? Do you mean change the log stored place?

Comment: we've got AKS and a DR, not we want to enable the logging and monitoring for AKS but challenge is we do not want to install the ELK or prometheus-grafana inside the cluster ? 
I am open for best suggestion which would fit the bill.

Comment: If you don't want to use Azure monitor for AKS, and still want to monitor the AKS outside the cluster. Maybe you can put the AKS cluster and your VM that installed ELK stack as you said in the same Vnet, so that the pods in the AKS cluster can communicate with your VM, it alse means communicate with your ELK stack.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [fluentd](https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/kubernetes-fluentd)? Logging agent that collects logs and able to ship logs to Elastic search.

**UPDATE**

I just found some examples in `kops` repo. You can check [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/tree/master/addons/logging-elasticsearch)

Comment: if I configure the fluentd inside the cluster do I need any of the ELK  core components to be installed on cluster?

Comment: No, `fluentd` daemonset will take care of shipping logs to elastic search.

Answer (score 0):

You can run [filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-getting-started.html) to collect logs from kubernetes.
Follow the instruction of [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/running-on-kubernetes.html) on link:

After you download [kubernetes.yaml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elastic/beats/master/deploy/kubernetes/filebeat-kubernetes.yaml) change:

```
- name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
  value: [your elastic search domain]
- name: ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
  value: "9200"
- name: ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME
  value: elastic
- name: ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD
  value: changeme
```

Pay attention! You need admin privileges for creating filebeat ServiceAccount

Answer (score 0):

We can use EFK stack for Kubernetes Logging and Monitoring. We need a Kubernetes cluster with following capabilities.

1. Ability to run privileged containers.
2. Helm and tiller enabled.
3. Statefulsets and dynamic volume provisioning capability: Elasticsearch is deployed as stateful set on Kubernetes. It’s best to use latest version of Kubernetes (v 1.10 as of this writing)

Please refer https://platform9.com/blog/kubernetes-logging-and-monitoring-the-elasticsearch-fluentd-and-kibana-efk-stack-part-2-elasticsearch-configuration/ for step by step guide.

Answer (score 0):

You can use logging modules like Winston to ship logs to elastic with the plugins they provide

It is very direct and easy to setup

In my node application I used this 
[Winston plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-elasticsearch)